# Remove duplicates in array of arrays based on the lenght of string on 1st position. JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I have an array of arrays like this:

```
arr = 
[
  [0 ,  abc  ],
  [7 ,  def  ],
  [10,  ghi  ],
  [0 , abcjkl]
]
```

What I want is to find duplicates based on the value on 0th position (in my example: `[0, abc], [0, abcjkl]`) and remove the array with shorter string on 1st postiton. The result should look like this:

```
[
  [7 ,  def  ],
  [10,  ghi  ],
  [0 , abcjkl]
]
```

Thank you for any help.

**EDIT:**

I have working algorithm just doesnt seem like the best approach.

```
function findDupes(arr) {
  let dupe = null;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      if (arr[i] !== arr[j]) {
        if (arr[i][1] === arr[j][1]) {
          if (arr[i][0].length >= arr[j][0].length) {
            dupe = arr[j];
          } else {
            dupe = arr[i];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return dupe;
}

let check = findDupes(arr);
while (check) {
    filteredValues.splice(arr.indexOf(check), 1);
    check = findDupes(arr);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @expressjs123 I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce the array to a Map, and when a duplicate with a greater length is found, remove previous and add the new one:

```js
const data = [
  [0 ,  'abc'  ],
  [7 ,  'def'  ],
  [10,  'ghi'  ],
  [0 , 'abcjkl']
]

const result = Array.from(
 data.reduce((acc, row) => {
  const [key, value] = row
 
  if(value.length > (acc.get(key)?.length ?? 0)) {
    acc.delete(key)
    acc.set(key, value)
  }
  
  return acc
 } , new Map())
)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use hash map to solve this.Loop through each inner array and put elements in hash Map like let hashMap = {0:'abc',10:'ghi'}.

If the key already exists in hash Map, check the if the value's length is smaller than new value, if so, replace.